# How to change table cell color based on its value PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am fetching data from the MySQL database and displaying it on a HTML table. I want to change the cell background color based on cell value with php.

I already went through with this answer
[how to change table cell color depending on values in php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45367268/23540622)
But this is not an answer to my question. In this answer comparing values by column by column. in my situation, I cannot do that because I have 32 columns in my table. Dep 1 to Dep 32. I tried to do that with the in_array function.but its now working.

Here is my idea
[Please refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxY0n.png)

```
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $sn=1;
  while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
//$color = $data['s'] == "Single Needle" ? "red" : ($data['s'] == "Double Needle" ? "yellow" : "green"); 
if (in_array("Cotton", $data))
{
$color="red";
}
else if (in_array("Denim", $data))
{
  $color="green";
}
else if (in_array("Linen", $data))
{
  $color="yellow";
}
 ?>

 <tr >
<td <?php echo' style="background-color:'.$color.'" '
 ?> ><?php echo $data['s']; ?> </td>

<td <?php echo' style="background-color:'.$color.'" '
 ?> ><?php echo $data['d']; ?> </td>

   <td><?php echo $data['Dep 1']; ?> </td>
   <td><?php echo $data['Dep 2']; ?> </td>
   <td><?php echo $data['Dep 3']; ?> </td>
   <td><?php echo $data['Dep 4']; ?> </td>
   <td><?php echo $data['Dep 5']; ?> </td>
   <td><?php echo $data['Dep 6']; ?> </td>
   <td><?php echo $data['Dep 7']; ?> </td>

 <tr>
 <?php
  $sn++;}} else { ?>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="8">No data found</td>
    </tr>
 <?php } ?>
  </table>
```

Plese help me. i am new to programming

Comment: You are asking a wrong question. It appears that you *already know* how to change a table cell color based on value. Why even asking that? Your problem is that you are using it in the wrong place. Instead of in_array you must compare the **actual value,** `if ($data['Dep 1'] === 'Cotton')` and add this condition for the cell that echoes $data['Dep 1'], not the cell that echoes  $data['s']

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes I know how to do it like this if ($data['Dep 1'] === 'Cotton'). but my problem in my case my table has 32 columns.i want to know is there any easy method to do it without writing above code to every column

Comment: THEN you should have asked THIS question, "how to do it without writing above code to every column". And the answer is somewhat surprising, your database structure is wrong. It seems you need another database table instead of those dep 1, dep2 columns. so you will get them in separate rows and could use a loop instead of writing all 32 by hand

Comment: Maintain a separate table for this, like `config`. Then, you can adjust your code based on that.

Comment: You should probably start with a _loop_, to output each of your 32 `Dep` columns. `<?php for($i=1; $i<=32; ++$i): ?><td><?php echo $data['Dep ' . $i]; ?></td><?php endfor; ?>` And then you integrate your color assignment based on the current column value, into that as well.